# Update multiple variables in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `table` with Sum of Amounts for Each Weekday (Sunday to Saturday) . Table structure is as below.

[image]

I need to assign these table values into parameters. For E.g : I need to assign sum of  rdate `'2015-11-15'` i.e `324` to a variable @sundayval , 374 to variable @mondayval etc...

How to do this In a single update query. I have tried out with Case statement,
But it only assigns value to variable @saturdayval .

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Do you know, ahead of time, what dates you want to store these values for?

Comment: What will you do with these variables once they're assigned? In general, it's better to keep the data in a tabular data structure as long as possible (preferably, right up until the point where the data exits SQL Server and something else (a report builder, an application, etc) takes over responsibility for the processing.

Comment: like @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, it gives me sum of saturdayval i.e last day only. Same as what i have tried

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have to pass these variables as inputs to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - let's do it this way: the `else` case is set to return itself, so each variable essentially aggregates as a coalesce.  Note: I don't have any way to test this right now. :)

```
SELECT
    @sundayval = case when DATEPART(weekday, rdate) = 1 then sum else @sundayval end
    , @mondayval = case when DATEPART(weekday, rdate) = 2 then sum else @mondayval end
    , @tuesdayval = case when DATEPART(weekday, rdate) = 3 then sum else @tuesdayval end
    , @wednesdayval = case when DATEPART(weekday, rdate) = 4 then sum else @wednesdayval end
    , @thursdayval = case when DATEPART(weekday, rdate) = 5 then sum else @thursdayval end
    , @fridayval = case when DATEPART(weekday, rdate) = 6 then sum else @fridayval end
    , @saturdayval = case when DATEPART(weekday, rdate) = 7 then sum else @saturdayval end
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: So, it processes one row, say, for tuesday, and assigns `@tuesdayval` a value and all other variables are set to null. Then it processes a second row, say, for friday, and assigns `@fridayval` a value and all other variables (*including* `@tuesdayval`) are set to null. I'd suggest some aggregates are needed here.

Comment: like @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, it gives me sum of saturdayval i.e last day only. Same as what i have tried

Answer (score 2):

This does the job. It doesn't depend on any particulat [`DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms181598.aspx) settings - it instead uses an arbitrarily chosen sunday (I picked 17th May this year) (what I usually refer to as a "known good" date because it has the property we're looking for, in this case the right day of the week):

```
declare @t table ([sum] int not null,rdate datetime2 not null)
insert into @t([sum],rdate) values
(324,'20151115'),
(374,'20151116'),
(424,'20151117'),
(474,'20151118'),
(524,'20151119'),
(574,'20151120'),
(624,'20151121')

declare @sundayval int
declare @mondayval int
declare @tuesdayval int
declare @wednesdayval int
declare @thursdayval int
declare @fridayval int
declare @saturdayval int

select
    @sundayval    = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,rdate) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150517') THEN [sum] END),
    @mondayval    = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,rdate) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150518') THEN [sum] END),
    @tuesdayval   = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,rdate) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150519') THEN [sum] END),
    @wednesdayval = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,rdate) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150520') THEN [sum] END),
    @thursdayval  = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,rdate) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150521') THEN [sum] END),
    @fridayval    = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,rdate) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150522') THEN [sum] END),
    @saturdayval  = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,rdate) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150523') THEN [sum] END)
from @t

select @sundayval,@mondayval,@tuesdayval,@wednesdayval,@thursdayval,@fridayval,@saturdayval
```

Result:

```
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
324         374         424         474         524         574         624
```

Answer (score 0):

I have No idea Whether a Single `UPDATE` Statement will do this. I have assigned value for Each `Variable` like as Below,

```
SELECT @SunTotal =  [sum]
                    FROM [table] 
                    where rdate = @Startdate

SELECT @MonTotal =  [sum]
                    FROM [table] 
                    where rdate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@Startdate)

SO ON...
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know if my updated answer will work... :)